# Adjusting additional_info info before adding to sales_flat_order_payment

Tags: magento-1.8, php, authorize.net

I want to remove some information from being added to the serialized column called additional_info before it is saved  to the sales_flat_order_payment

I see that there is a function called:

unsAdditionalInformation()

which seems to be what I am looking for. However, I am not really sure where to call it without messing up something else from the order flow. I think it should be added just before the additional_info column is saved to the DB. But not sure where that is.

I am using authorize.net with magento 1.8

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen to one event that happens before saving to the database (not sure which one is right for you, it depends where and when you want to do this) but you could try with this one: 
 **sales_order_place_before**

And then in the observer you can adjust the value of the attribute you want and then it will be saved as you want.